# Caffe and TensorFlow Protobuf - Maintain different Version

Tags: python, version, protocol-buffers, caffe, tensorflow

I have installed Caffe on my Ubuntu15.10x64 Machine with `protobuf 2.6.1`. Also, as of today, I installed TensorFlow with `virtualenv` but TensorFlow needs `protobuf 3.0`. From what I have read, `virtualenv` supports using different libraries for python projects. Can I safely `pip install --upgrade protobuf` inside the (tensorflow) virtualenv without disrupting my Caffe install - thus having `protobuf 2.6` as default, and `protobuf 3.0` in my virtualenv used by TensorFlow?

Or is the only solution to install with Docker or Create a Clone in a Virtual Machine? Better than nothing, but I would like to use my GPU and full power.

Thanks for help and clarification.

Edit:

So, this is what happens when I try to update protobuf ->

```
(tensorflow)peter@UNIGMA:~$ pip install --upgrade protobuf 
Requirement already up-to-date: protobuf in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages 
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from protobuf) 
Cleaning up...
```

If i check the version this is what it returns ->

```
(tensorflow)peter@UNIGMA:~$ pip show protobuf
---
Name: protobuf
Version: 2.6.1
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: setuptools
(tensorflow)peter@UNIGMA:~$ pip -V
pip 1.5.6 from /home/peter/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Do I have to manually update protobuf? I presume that I would create a `protobuf` folder inside `./tensorflow/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` with the version I need?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your virtualenv doesn't see packages from outside, so you should not have protobuf visible in your virtualenv at all, even though you have it installed globally in the system (or in the Caffe's virtualenv, depending on your setup).

It should be safe for you to run `pip install protobuf` inside the TensorFlow's virtualenv, it will not disrupt your global setup or any other virtualenv you have.

Comment: Note that protobuf-python likes to use protobuf-c++ as a C extension. Will virtualenv actually containerize that? I don't know much about virtualenv but it would surprise me.

Comment: `(tensorflow)peter@UNIGMA:~$ pip install --upgrade protobuf
Requirement already up-to-date: protobuf in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from protobuf)
Cleaning up...`
It sill seems to reference my local protobuf if i am seeing this right.